# Opengl Precision Conversion Error compiling error E0415

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Here I want to implement a simple OpenGL function which is similar to `glulookat()`:

```
mat4 Transform::lookAt(vec3 eye, vec3 up) {
vec3 w = glm::normalize(eye);
vec3 u = glm::normalize(glm::cross(up, w));
vec3 v = glm::cross(w, u);
mat4 r = (
    u.x, u.y, u.z, 0,
    v.x, v.y, v.z, 0,
    w.x, w.y, w.z, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
    );

mat4 t = (
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -eye.x,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -eye.y,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -eye.z,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    );

mat4 result = glm::transpose(r)*glm::transpose(t);
return result;
```

}

VS2017 told me that:

```
Error (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "double" to "glm::detail::tmat4x4<glm::core::type::precision::lowp_float>"
```

I know this problem might be caused by type conversion, however, After I modified all `0.0` to `0`, similar problems occur again (no suitable XXX from `"int"` to XXX). I could not figure out how to solve it. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Was there something wrong with [`glm::lookAt()`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html#gaf8eef81da1ad09f6a8920101c01eaae4) in [`GLM_GTC_matrix_transform`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html)?

Comment: Without having VS2017 at hand, but `= (` looks rather strange to me. Shouldn't it just be `mat4 r(...);`?

Comment: Wich Opengl version?

Comment: @Rama: OpenGL isn't relevant at all here. It's just about glm.

Comment: @BLD I think *OpenGL Shading Language Version* can be relevant, because Han is using `glm::transpose` https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/transpose.xhtml

Comment: Use float literals instead of double literals. That is `0.f` instead of `0.0`.

Comment: @BDL Thanks! It's a stupid mistake, I really have to consolidate my fundations...

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Thanks for your help. It's a stupic syntax mistake.

Comment: @Rama Thank you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your matrix declaration code, `mat4 r = (...)`
is wrong. The correct syntax should be:

```
mat4 r(...);
```

(without = inbetween)